# I updated ruby gems, and now i get parse tree errors and deprecation warnings everywhere!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

The error in short:

```
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:275:in `==': undefined method `name' for "ParseTree":String (NoMethodError)
```

using

```
ruby 1.8.7
rails 2.3.8
rubygems 1.8.5
```

what do I do?

I've tried deleting the rubygems folder, and doing a clean rubygems install... but the above errer remains.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There have been a lot of structural changes in rubygems that has caught a lot of people by surprise. It has introduced incompatibility problems with a number of common applications and frameworks.

You may need to roll back to a version of rubygems that works with your system, such as 1.6.0:

```
gem update --system 1.6.0
```

If that doesn't work, you may want to investigate [slimgems](http://gnuu.org/2011/06/01/slimgems-a-drop-in-replacement-for-rubygems/) which is a 1.3.7 fork of rubygems that is intended to remedy these compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

it's worthy to try update bundeler

d:\workspace\dongxf\projects\ruby\arbref>rails s
D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:183:in `stub_source_index170': uninitialized constant Gem::SourceIndex (NameError)
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:303:in`stub_rubygems'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:246:in `replace_entrypoints'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in`setup'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in`'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in`rescue in require'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from d:/workspace/dongxf/projects/ruby/arbref/config/boot.rb:6:in`'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in`require'
        from script/rails:5:in `'

d:\workspace\dongxf\projects\ruby\arbref>gem update bundle
Updating installed gems
Updating bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.3.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.2
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.3.2
Installing darkfish documentation for bundler-1.3.2
Gems updated: bundler

d:\workspace\dongxf\projects\ruby\arbref>rails s
=> Booting Thin

[image]